# How do i use the JSON result from a function, which i call in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, json

```
Algorithm.prototype.showAnalysisResultFromFile = function (filename) {
    var self = this;
    require('fs').readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       if (err)
           throw err;
       var transactions = ArrayUtils.readCSVToArray(data, ',');
       var analysisResult = self.analyze(transactions);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(analysisResult.associationRules));
```

How do I use the result when I call this function in another file?
I have tried storing the value in a variable and return the variable, but when called in another file and parse it, value returns as undefined.

```
var x = new Apriori.Algorithm(0.15, 0.6, false).showAnalysisResultFromFile('DATASET.csv');
console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use callback,

```
Algorithm.prototype.showAnalysisResultFromFile = function (filename, callback) {
            var self = this;
            require('fs').readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                var transactions = ArrayUtils.readCSVToArray(data, ',');
                var analysisResult = self.analyze(transactions);
               callback(analysisResult.associationRules);
    });
  }


new Apriori.Algorithm(0.15, 0.6, false).showAnalysisResultFromFile('DATASET.csv', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: just google it, http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/